# How to git pull regardless of the current state?

Tags: git, version-control

I want to get the current upstream regardless of what I have in the local repo.
More specifically, I want to avoid merge/conflicts.
Is there a way to do this with pull?
git clone takes a lot of time.

Comment: do `git fetch` then force update your branch with something like `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: This comment deserves to be the answer.